# How to use multiple lines on react chart

Tags: node.js, reactjs, charts

**Hello, I'm working on an application where I need to display a given pricing to the user for, say, 10 to 15 seconds. To do this, I need to draw a tracing line for 10 seconds in a row as seen in the figure below.
Here's an example
https://ibb.co/YtBZdvs
And my application stack is nodejs, Reactjs and i am looking for chart solution**

Comment: can you post the code you have

Comment: i don't have code yet because i don't know what chart library should i use

Comment: https://blog.logrocket.com/top-5-react-chart-libraries/  pick anyone

Comment: I've already tried these, but they don't fully satisfy my needs since I want a tracing line on a chart that is drawn by function and deleted after a while.